# What do the Letters A and M mean to the preprocessor

Tags: c, debugging, c-preprocessor

So I am studying C and I came across this

```
 #ifndef _dbg_h_
 #define _dbg_h

 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<errno.h>
 #ifdef NDEBUG
 #define debug(M,...)// I do not know why M is an argument here
 #else 
 #define debug(M,...)fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG %s:%d: " M "\n",\
 _FILE_,_LINE_,##_VA_ARGS_)
 #endif
 #define clean_errno()(errno==0?"None":strerror(errno))

 #define log_err(M,...)fprintf(stderr,\"[ERROR](%s:%d: errno: %s)" M "\n"
 _FILE_,_LINE_ ,\clean_errno(),##_VA_ARGS_)
 ...
 #define check(A,M,...)if(!(A)){\         /*why is A an arg here */
  log_err(M,##_VA_ARGS_);errno=0;goto error;}
```

Why do these need M and A as arguments and where are these being declared/initialized

Comment: These are arguments, as you already noticed. They are passed like arguments to functions.

Comment: What is your **specific** problem? What did youi not find answered in a C book? or online resource?

Comment: `int n = 42;` - what does the letter n mean to the C compiler?

Comment: N is an identifer that is for a variable of type int

Comment: There is no type for M in this code

Comment: @bordenE, `M` and `A` are not C variables, they are *macro arguments*.  Macro arguments are not explicitly typed and do not have different types -- all macro arguments are sequences of preprocessing tokens and whitespace spans.

Answer (score 2):

The names `M` and `A` have no particular meaning to the preprocessor.

`M`, for example, is the name of the first parameter of the `debug` macro. The name `M`, when it occurs in the definition of the `debug` macro, is replaced by the value of the first argument passed when you invoke `debug`.

The `...` means it's a *variadic* macro, one that can take a variable number of arguments.

A simpler example:

```
#define MY_MACRO(ARG) (2*(ARG))

printf("%d\n", MY_MACRO(10));
```

In the invocation `MY_MACRO(10)`, the name `ARG` is replaced by `10`, causing the entire macro invocation to expand to `(2*(10))`. (The extra parentheses are to avoid problems with operator precedence.)